# Hide Share Dashboard option in quick sight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I need to hide the **ShareDashboard** option in  quicksight for Author users, like how this is restricted for Reader users.

Is it possible to hide this menu options for few author users in my account ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to share your dashboard with user name 'xyz'. When share dashboard with 'xyz' user, select 'Viewer' under permission not 'Co-owner'.

Using AWS Console (If you've already shared with 'xyz', then):

1. Open your dashboard
2. Under share option select 'Share dashboard'
3. Click 'manage dashboard access'
4. Find user ('xyz') that you want to revoke 'share dashboard' permission
5. Make sure that that user have 'Viewer' permission, if not than change to 'viewer'

If you want to use [Dashboard API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.update_dashboard_permissions)